# Deep into Ruby class_eval and instance_eval

Tags: ruby, instance-eval, class-eval

`class_eval` and `instance_eval` are quite predictable in such cases like defining methods. I also understand the difference between class's instance and class's singleton (aka eigenclass).

BUT

I cannot figure out the only thing like following:
Let's say, for some strage purposes, we want make existing class to be singleton.

```
class A; end
class B; end

A.class_eval do
  private :new
end

B.instance_eval do
  private :new
end
```

in both cases got

```
NameError: undefined method 'new' for class
Did you mean?  new
```

yes, I mean exactly this method.

Moreover, these two variants give the same result, like `self` points at class object in both cases

```
A.class_eval do
  class << self
    private :new
  end
end

A.new
=> NoMethodError: private method 'new' called for A:Class

B.instance_eval do
  class << self
    private :new
  end
end

B.new
=> NoMethodError: private method 'new' called for B:Class
```

How come? Can anybody shed the light on this?

Comment: `new` in classes in Ruby is actually defined using `initialize`. Try replacing `:new` with `:initialize`

Comment: @casraf That's not correct. `new` is defined by Class (the superclass of all classes) and does two things (from [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Class.html#method-c-new)): "Calls `allocate` to create a new object of *class*’s class, then invokes that object’s `initialize` method, passing it *args*. This is the method that ends up getting called whenever an object is constructed using .new." When you define (override) `initialize` in a class it does not define or change `new`, and `new` can be overridden like any other class method (though I can't think of a reason to).

Comment: My bad. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a peek into what self is here:

```
class A
  puts self.inspect

  class << self
    puts self.inspect
  end
end

A.class_eval {
  puts self.inspect

  class << self
    puts self.inspect
  end
}

A.instance_eval{
  puts self.inspect

  class << self
    puts self.inspect
  end
}
```

We get the following output:

```
A
#<Class:A>
A
#<Class:A>
A
#<Class:A>
```

The class_eval method is defined for modules (and thus classes) and evaluates within the context of the module (class). The instance_eval method evaluates within the context of a BasicObject. It seems that in these cases the two (three actually) are the same thing.

However, I know for a fact that if methods are *created* inside the eval block that class_eval creates instance methods and instance_eval creates class methods. There is already an excellent posting for that observation: